# WeekOfYear column getting null in the SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here I am writing the SQL statement for spark.sql but I am not able to get the WEEKOFYEAR converted to week of the year and getting a null in the Output
Below I have shown the expression of what I a using

Input Data

```
InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,01-12-2010 8.26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
536365,71053,WHITE METAL LANTERN,6,01-12-2010 8.26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84406B,CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER,8,01-12-2010 8.26,2.75,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84029G,KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE,6,01-12-2010 8.26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
```

SQL CODE

```
val summarySQlTest = spark.sql(
  """
    |select Country,WEEKOFYEAR(InvoiceDate)as WeekNumber,
    |count(distinct(InvoiceNo)) as NumInvoices,
    |sum(Quantity) as TotalQuantity,
    |round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice),2) as InvoiceValue
    |from sales
    |group by Country,WeekNumber
    |""".stripMargin
).show()
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
     +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
     |       Country|WeekNumber|NumInvoices|TotalQuantity|InvoiceValue|
     +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
     |         Spain|        49|          1|           67|      174.72|
     |       Germany|        48|         11|         1795|     3309.75|
```

Output I am getting

```
    +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
    |       Country|WeekNumber|NumInvoices|TotalQuantity|InvoiceValue|
    +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
    |         Spain|      null|          1|           67|      174.72|
    |       Germany|      null|         11|         1795|     3309.75|
```

For the desired output I used this, But I want to solve the same in the spark.sql

Also it would be great if anyone can explain the what is actually happening here
**(to_date(col("InvoiceDate"),"dd-MM-yyyy H.mm")**

```
val knowFunc=  invoicesDF.withColumn("InvoiceDate",to_date(col("InvoiceDate"),"dd-MM-yyyy H.mm"))
    .where("year(InvoiceDate) == 2010")
    .withColumn("WeekNumber",weekofyear(col("InvoiceDate")))
    .groupBy("Country","WeekNumber")
    .agg(sum("Quantity").as("TotalQuantity"),
    round(sum(expr("Quantity*UnitPrice")),2).as("InvoiceValue")).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `InvoiceDate` column to date type first (using `to_date`), before you can call `weekofyear`. I guess this also answers your last question.

```
val summarySQlTest = spark.sql(
  """
    |select Country,WEEKOFYEAR(to_date(InvoiceDate,'dd-MM-yyyy H.mm')) as WeekNumber,
    |count(distinct(InvoiceNo)) as NumInvoices,
    |sum(Quantity) as TotalQuantity,
    |round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice),2) as InvoiceValue
    |from sales
    |group by Country,WeekNumber
    |""".stripMargin
).show()
```

Comment: Spark is just silently returning a null here, instead of an exception because of trying to use weekofyear with a string?

Comment: @Andrew I guess that was it now its running fine

Comment: @mck I wanted to ask you we gave this format  => 'dd-MM-yyyy H.mm' because we need to convert the String which was already in date format to the actual date format I suppose . so if my invoice date won't contain H.mm then I would have just written 'dd-MM-yyyy' ??? Help me understand this too

Comment: Yes, the date format should correspond to the date format of the string column. Spark cannot understand strings as dates, unless you explicitly convert them to dates using `to_date` and providing a correct date format.